# Copy a range of cells after meeting criteria

Tags: vba, excel

I need to do a copy of a range of cell after meeting the conditions as follows:

whenever Cells(15,15) of sheet1 is equals to cells(14,j). Firstcell will be equals to cells(14,j). Same concepts for secondcell.

After that I will need to do a copy of the cells between Firstcell and Secondcell. This is when I start to see the runtime error 91.

Assume that I have defined lastCol. My code:

```
Dim firstcell as range, secondcell as range

If Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(15, 10) <> "" And Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(15, 15) <> "" Then

    For j = 10 To lastCol

        If Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(15, 15).Text = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(14, j).Text Then

            firstcell = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(15, j)

        End If

        If Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(15, 13).Text = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(14, j).Text Then

            secondcell = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(15, j)

        End If

    Range(firstcell, secondcell ).copy

    Next j

End If
```

Comment: You have 2 `if..end if` conditions. If first condition is not met, firstcell could be undefined/null/something undesirable. If second condition is not met, secondcell could be undefined/null/something undesirable. You may need to handle do `Range(firstcell, secondcell).copy` only if both firstcell and secondcell have desirable content in them.

Comment: What zfus said plus you should change `firstcell = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(15, j)` to `set firstcell = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(15, j)`  Same for assigning secondcell.

Comment: @zfus I am assuming firstcell and secondcell will definitely meet its condition. Its just the matter of which column it will be at.

Comment: @sobigen I have tried to what was suggested, it is giving me a runtime error even if I tried to change the Dim from range to variant

Comment: What is findSDColTC?

Comment: Even if it was a variant you'd still need `Set`.  If you don't use `Set` you get the value in the cell instead of the Range object.  Do you need to move the `Next j` line up above the copy statement maybe to fix the other issue?  That would make more sense to me since they way it is you're copying the range every time through the loop.

Comment: @zfus It was another variable I used in my code.. I tried to simplify it when I post it and I left that out. I apologize for the confusion. Have already made the necessary amendments

Comment: @Sobigen I see. Now it works after I shift the next j up as suggested. Thank you so much for the help! :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer determined from comments:

```
Dim firstcell as range, secondcell as range

If Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(15, 10) <> "" And Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(15, 15) <> "" Then
    For j = 10 To lastCol
        If Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(15, 15).Text = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(14, j).Text Then
            set firstcell = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(15, j)
        End If

        If Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(15, 13).Text = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(14, j).Text Then
            set secondcell = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(15, j)
        End If
    Next j
    Range(firstcell, secondcell ).copy
End If
```